# how to make multidimensional array using my variables

Tags: php

From here i have **start_date** and **due_date** and also some others variables using this values i have to make multidimensional array,start date is `2018-01-01` end date `2018-01-03` means 3 time loop should run with the corresponding date.

**My Variables**

```
$start_date = "2018-01-01";
$start_time = "01:30 PM";
$due_date="2018-01-03";
$due_time = "11:30 AM"
$project="10001";
$assign_to="G2E0357";
```

My expected output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-01
            [t_project] => 10001
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 01:30 PM
            [t_end_time] => 11:30 AM
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-02
            [t_project] => 10001
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 01:30 PM
            [t_end_time] => 11:30 AM

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-03
            [t_project] => 10001
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 01:30 PM
            [t_end_time] => 11:30 AM
        )
)
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: Please don't use blockquote for text (I edited that out) and remove those from all of your previous posts, thank you. FYI: This behaviour is flaggable for moderation. I even told you here https://stackoverflow.com/q/48380180/  yet you kept on using blockquotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can by some steps like mentions in code **comment** :

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$start_date = "2018-01-01";
$start_time = "01:30 PM";
$due_date="2018-01-03";
$due_time = "11:30 AM";
$project="10001";
$assign_to="G2E0357";

$glopal_array = array();
$data_array = list_days(strtotime($start_date),strtotime($due_date));// get all days in array
foreach($data_array as $item) {//loop in day array
    $res_arr_values  = array("allocation_date"=>$item,"t_project"=>$project,"t_assign_to"=>$assign_to,"t_start_time"=>$start_time,"t_end_time"=>$due_time);//set up 2d arry with keys
    array_push($glopal_array,$res_arr_values);//push the array the global array
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($glopal_array);//print glopal array
echo "</pre>";


function list_days($date_from,$date_to){
    $arr_days = array();
    $arr_days[] = date('o-m-d',$date_from);
    $day_passed = ($date_to - $date_from); //seconds
    $day_passed = ($day_passed/86400); //days

    $counter = 1;
    $day_to_display = $date_from;
    while($counter < $day_passed){
        $day_to_display += 86400;
        //echo date("F j, Y \n", $day_to_display);
        $arr_days[] = date('o-m-d',$day_to_display);
        $counter++;
    }
    $arr_days[] = date('o-m-d',$date_to);

    return $arr_days;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]